# Find or replace a string in word documents in a given folder

Tags: ms-word

How to find or replace a word in the documents in the given folder

Is there is a tool or any script is available to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finding text is straightforward. There are several ways to do it, including using the Windows search utility. Here's an article with several methods: [Search through the content of multiple Word documents](https://seekfast.org/blog/search-text-in-documents/how-can-i-search-through-the-content-of-multiple-word-documents/)

To find and replace, you can use a free text editor like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.7.1.html). It has a very good Find in Files utility. There are many other utilities that can do this, some paid and some free.

Finally, you can write a VBA macro that will find and replace all documents in a folder. Here's a page with a macro listing that does that: [How to Find and Replace Contents in Multiple Word Documents](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/find-replace-contents-multiple-word-documents/)

Comment: Can we use Notepad++ for word document i.e doc and docx files?? Is any plugin needs to be installed to do this?

Comment: Yes, here's a page on how to use NotePad++ for find and replace operations in Word files: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-find-and-replace-words-in-multiple-files/